# How can I initialize an array from another in one line or in constructor initialiser list?

Tags: c++, arrays

If I have a class with an array in it, how can I do this?

```
template <int size>
struct StructWithArray
{
    StructWithArray(const char (&arrArg)[size]) : /* Can't fill here??? */{ /* Can't loop 
or memcpy here as it's const*/}
    const char arr[size];
}
```

Likewise:

```
void afunc()
{
     char somearray[] = "Something from somewhere";
     static const char somearray2[sizeof(somearray)]; // = .... Can't assign to anything.
// So then I memcpy, except it's const and I can't
// You can't go const char somearray2[5] = memcpy 
// Actually I might want it constexpr too
}
```

Does anyone else find this ridiculously difficult? I'm trying to copy the **func** or **FUNCTION** array into my own memory because I have to in order to pass the memory to a template parameter. Though even generally this seems hard. I thought about `std::array`, how does it do it?

Comment: `std::array` can't be initialized from plain array either. It can be initialized from another `std::array` for the same reason your `StructWithArray` can be initialized from another `StructWithArray`: the implicitly defined copy constructor knows how to copy data members, including those of array type. In fact, `std::array` looks very similar to `StructWithArray` - it's a struct with an array member, and nothing else.

Comment: s/`const char arr[size]`/`char arr[size]`/

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Wow this is crazy. All I want is a const char array filled with the name of the function from __func__ or __FUNCTION__, because I can't rely on the address of those as they are implementation dependent. There's no such as thing const char myarray[6] = --- fill with something ----; ?

Comment: @super How do you copy into a const buffer? I thought that wasn't allowed, including const_cast if it was originally declared const as the compiler may put it in read-only memory?

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
template <int size>
struct StructWithArray
{
    template <std::size_t... Is>
    StructWithArray(const char (&arrArg)[size], std::index_sequence<Is...>)
      : arr{arrArg[Is]...} {}

    StructWithArray(const char (&arrArg)[size])
      : StructWithArray(arrArg, std::make_index_sequence<size>{})
    {}

    const char arr[size];
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/f5fKG4935)

Answer (score 1):

Since C++20, you have what is called [`std::to_array()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/to_array):

```cpp
#include <array>

template <int size>
struct StructWithArray
{
    StructWithArray(const char (&arrArg)[size]) : arr{std::to_array(arrArg)} {}
    const std::array<char, size> arr;
};

void afunc()
{
     char somearray[] = "Something from somewhere";
     static const std::array<char, sizeof somearray> somearray2 = std::to_array(somearray);
}
```

For C++14/17, you can just define it yourself (Below is an implementation from cppreference.com):

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <cstddef>

namespace detail {
    template <class T, std::size_t N, std::size_t... I>
    constexpr std::array<std::remove_cv_t<T>, N> to_array_impl(T (&&a)[N], std::index_sequence<I...>) {
        return { { std::move(a[I])... } };
    }
}
 
template <class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::array<std::remove_cv_t<T>, N> to_array(T (&&a)[N]) {
    return detail::to_array_impl(std::move(a), std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <array>

template<typename type_t, size_t N>
static constexpr std::array<type_t, N> make_array(const type_t(&arr)[N])
{
    std::array<type_t, N> retval{};
    for (size_t i = 0; i < retval.size(); ++i) retval[i] = arr[i];
    return retval;
}

template <size_t N>
struct StructWithArray
{
    constexpr StructWithArray(const char(&arrArg)[N]) :
        m_arr(std::move(make_array(arrArg)))
    {
    }

    constexpr auto values() const noexcept
    {
        return m_arr;
    }

    const std::array<char, N> m_arr;
};

int main()
{
    constexpr char arr[]{1,2,3,4,5};
    StructWithArray s("Hello"); // automatically deduces size 6 (5 chars + 0)
    StructWithArray s2(arr);

    constexpr auto a = make_array(arr);
    static_assert(a[0] == 1);
    static_assert(a[1] == 2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you do retval[i] = arr[i];  you're constructing a temporary, and then writing into the array, does this mean that you can only make non-const arrays?

Comment: Like for example if you pass const char[ ] to make_array then type_t of std::array will be const char, then how do you construct the temporary and then write into it with operator [ ] ?

Comment: Good point I checked your first question , if you make m_arr in the struct const it will still work.
Also the constructor of std::array and operator[] are constexpr. So everything is done at compile time

Comment: I think there is no problem since everything is evaluated at compile time. So by the time you start the program runtime everything will be "baked in" and const.

Comment: Okay I made a mistake, the arr[5] needs to be constexpr too, to fully work at compile time. Updated the example.